# Client-server logic

Tags: client, client-server

I'm sorry if this is a trivial question. I've heard about client-server logic many times, in job requirement and in IT sites, too. I don't really believe that I get that "client-server logic". Anybody can provide me some good books about that and related things or client-server logic is just a trivial thing to understand?
Thanks for reading. Any help is appreciated. 
PS: I have accepted Garrett Smallwood's answer  because it's good, but I'm willing to know many more books about this topic. Thanks for any further suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read, and strongly suggest [Client/Server Survival Guide 3rd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471316156)

> Books on client/server computing are often dry and academic. Not so with the Client/Server Survival Guide, now in its third edition. The trio of authors--Jeri Edwards, Dan Harkey, and Robert Orfali--make the topic interesting with a down-to-earth style that covers the informational landscape without boring the reader to tears. Numerous nontechnical diagrams drive home important concepts quickly.
>   The first part consists of a comprehensive overview of client/server computing. In this critical introduction, the authors discuss the paradigm, the various flavors of servers, and the basics of two-tier and three-tier architectures. They also discuss how the client/server works in the real world and introduce the concepts of LAN, WAN, and other connection topologies.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model

> The client–server model of computing is a distributed application structure that partitions tasks or workloads between the providers of a resource or service, called servers, and service requesters, called clients. Often clients and servers communicate over a computer network on separate hardware, but both client and server may reside in the same system. A server machine is a host that is running one or more server programs which share their resources with clients. A client does not share any of its resources, but requests a server's content or service function. Clients therefore initiate communication sessions with servers which await incoming requests.

Comment: I read wiki before asking something here, but thanks for providing that ;)